# IF implementations in C#

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, functional-programming

The majority of developers write `IF` statements in the following way

```
if (condition)
{
    //Do something here
}
```

of course this considered normal but often can create nested code which is not so elegant and a bit ugly.
So the question is: Is possible to convert traditional `IF` statements to functional ones?

<sub>** This is an open question of possible ways to produce more readable code and i prefer not to accept any answer. I believe is better people to choose themselves the best solution for them and vote for the answer they chose.</sub>

Comment: Functional if statements? Can you show an example in other language you're trying to reproduce in c#?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "functional" either. "Functional statements" sounds like an oxymoron.

Comment: I think the greatest challenge is find an approach that produces better readable code than nested if statements. The two answers (so far) don't do that IMHO. I once programmed some sort of decision tree with a fluent API. I'll try to look into it later (if I can still find it) and come back to you.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek; i'm sorry but i don't have one in other language and it's supposed that this question is for C#. @molbdnilo; can you suggest me a better title? @Gert Arnold you are invited to post an answer! I would be glad to see your decision tree :)

Answer (score 14):

Although I have already added the response about the 'functional if' aka conditional expressions.  It seems something more is being asked for, and that is to facilitate a decision tree.  I referred to using monads as the best approach in a reply to that.  Here is how it's done.  If you haven't used monads before then this might seem like voodoo, but it's essentially a better way of doing what @Gert Arnold posted.

I will take Gert's idea of a decision tree based on the suitability of a client.  Instead of using the fluent style with lambdas making the decisions, I'll use LINQ.  Which is C#'s native support for monads.  The result of using the code will look like this:

```
        var client = new Client { 
            CriminalRecord = false, 
            UsesCreditCard = true, 
            YearsInJob = 10, 
            Income = 70000 
        };

        var decision = from reliable in ClientDecisions.Reliable
                       from wealthy in ClientDecisions.Wealthy
                       select "They're reliable AND wealthy";

        var result = decision(client);
        if (result.HasValue) Console.WriteLine(result.Value);

        decision = from reliableOrWealthy in Decision.Either(
                       ClientDecisions.Reliable,
                       ClientDecisions.Wealthy
                       )
                   from stable in ClientDecisions.Stable
                   select "They're reliable OR wealthy, AND stable";

        result = decision(client);
        if (result.HasValue) Console.WriteLine(result.Value);

        decision = from reliable in ClientDecisions.Reliable
                   from wealthy in ClientDecisions.Wealthy
                   from stable in ClientDecisions.Stable
                   select "They're reliable AND wealthy, AND stable";

        result = decision(client);
        if (result.HasValue) Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
```

The beauty of this approach is that it is fully composable.  You can work with small 'decision pieces' and combine them to make larger decisions.  All without any need for `if`.

In the above code you will see usage of a `ClientDecisions` static class.  This is holding some re-usable decision pieces:

```
public static class ClientDecisions
{
    public static Decision<Client, Client> Reliable =>
        from client in Decision.Ask<Client>()
        where !client.CriminalRecord && client.UsesCreditCard
        select client;

    public static Decision<Client, Client> Wealthy =>
        from client in Decision.Ask<Client>()
        where client.Income > 100000
        select client;

    public static Decision<Client, Client> Stable =>
        from client in Decision.Ask<Client>()
        where client.YearsInJob > 2
        select client;
}
```

**NOTE** This is not using `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`.  In C# it's possible to provide `Select`, `SelectMany` and `Where` methods for any type and if implemented correctly allows you to make any type into a monadic type.

Interestingly in this instance I will be making a delegate into a monad.  The reason for this is because we need a value passing into the computation.  This is the definition of the delegate:

```
public delegate DecisionResult<O> Decision<I,O>(I input);
```

The input in the examples above is `Client` and the output is `string`.  But notice that the delegate above returns a `DecisionResult<O>`, and not `O` (which would be the `string`).  This is because we propagate through the computation a property called `HasValue`.  If `HasValue` is `false` at any point then the computation ends.  This allows us to make decisions during the computation which stops the rest of the computation from executing.  This is the `DecisionResult<T>` class:

```
public struct DecisionResult<T>
{
    private readonly T value;
    public readonly bool HasValue;

    internal DecisionResult(bool hasValue, T value = default(T))
    {
        this.value = value;
        HasValue = hasValue;
    }

    public T Value =>
        HasValue
            ? value
            : throw new DecisionFailedException();
}
```

Next we'll add a couple of helper methods that will produce `DecisionResult<T>` values.  They will be used in the `Select`, `SelectMany` and `Where` methods later.

```
public static class DecisionResult
{
    public static DecisionResult<O> Nothing<O>() =>
        new DecisionResult<O>(false);

    public static DecisionResult<O> Return<O>(O value) =>
        new DecisionResult<O>(true,value);
}
```

Now that we have the core types we can write our `Select`, `SelectMany` and `Where` extension methods to the `Decision<I,O>` delegate (Yes, you can write extension methods for delegates!)

```
public static class Decision
{
    public static Decision<I, V> Select<I, U, V>(this Decision<I, U> self, Func<U, V> map) =>
        input =>
        {
            var res = self(input);
            return res.HasValue
                ? DecisionResult.Return(map(res.Value))
                : DecisionResult.Nothing<V>();
        };

    public static Decision<I, V> SelectMany<I, T, U, V>(
        this Decision<I, T> self,
        Func<T, Decision<I, U>> select,
        Func<T, U, V> project) =>
        input =>
        {
            var resT = self(input);
            if (resT.HasValue)
            {
                var resU = select(resT.Value)(input);
                return resU.HasValue
                    ? DecisionResult.Return(project(resT.Value, resU.Value))
                    : DecisionResult.Nothing<V>();
            }
            else
            {
                return DecisionResult.Nothing<V>();
            }
        };

    public static Decision<I, O> Where<I, O>(this Decision<I, O> self, Predicate<O> pred) =>
        input =>
        {
            var res = self(input);
            return res.HasValue
                ? pred(res.Value)
                    ? DecisionResult.Return(res.Value)
                    : DecisionResult.Nothing<O>()
                : DecisionResult.Nothing<O>();
        };
}
```

These are the methods that allow `Decision<I,O>` to be used in a LINQ expression.  We will need a couple of additional methods in the `Decision` class.  The first is `Ask<I>`, it simply gets the value that was passed to the computation and allows it to be used in the expression.  It's named `Ask` because this monad is very similar to the standard `Reader` monad from Haskell, and it's called `ask` by convention.

```
public static class Decision
{
    public static Decision<I,I> Ask<I>() =>
        input => DecisionResult.Return(input);
}
```

We also want to allow conditional operation, so we'll also add `Either<I,O>(...)` to `Decision`.  This takes any number of `Decision<I,O>` monads, runs through them one-by-one, if one succeeds it returns the result immediately, if not it carries on.  If none of the computations succeed then the whole computation will end.  This allows for 'or' type behaviour, and 'switch' style behaviour:

```
public static class Decision
{
    public static Decision<I, O> Either<I, O>( params Decision<I, O>[] decisions ) =>
        input =>
        {
            foreach(var decision in decisions)
            {
                var res = decision(input);
                if( res.HasValue )
                {
                    return res;
                }
            }
            return DecisionResult.Nothing<O>();
        };
}
```

We don't need 'logical and', because it can be implemented as a series of `from` expressions or `where` expressions.

Finally we need an exception type in case the programmer tries to use `.Value` in `DecisionResult<T>` when `.HasValue == false`.

```
public class DecisionFailedException : Exception
{
    public DecisionFailedException()
        :
        base("The decision wasn't made, and therefore doesn't have a value.")
    {
    }
}
```

Using this technique (and building on the extension methods) you can avoid using `if` entirely.  This is a truly functional technique.  Of course it's not idiomatic, but it's the most declarative way you'll find in C#.

Comment: Excellent implementation! +1

Comment: Thanks :)  I made a slight improvement.  Changed DecisionResult<T> to be a struct so it's more likely to be kept on the stack by the CLR and will therefore cause less GC pressure.

Comment: This is a nice job. I like the way you show how LINQ methods can be implemented to do a custom job. Still... it's a lot of code, producing a decision tree that evaluates one object. That's what nagged me about "my" decision tree. Some decisions require a client and bank accounts, others a client and geographical records, etc. In my first efforts to employ the tree I found myself creating DTO's that carried all information required to traverse one tree. A change in a tree required a modified DTO. The code just broke too easily. The final decision was: ditch it.

Comment: Once the Decision monad has been written you don't need to create any more specialised ones.  It will work with any type and it will even work with anonymous types, so you don't have to create DTO classes.

I created the ClientDecisions class just to show how it's possible to re-use components.  Which makes building decision trees properly compositional.

Other benefits are you can inject different 'rules' by providing an interface that provides 'decisions'.  Imagine if ClientDecisions wasn't static, and was passed to a function which used it like the example above.

Comment: (ran out of space on the last comment) - if you need a changing input value throughout the tree then it's possible to modify the above code to work more like a State monad rather than a Reader monad.  So instead of just calling Decision.Ask() to get the input, you could call Decision.Put() as well.

Check here for info on how the Reader and State monads differ: https://github.com/louthy/csharp-monad

Comment: That's very interesting! I have to take a much deeper look into it to understand the benefits, but I'll certainly do that.

Answer (score 5):

There already is a 'functional if' aka 'conditional expression':

```
bool value = true;

var result = value 
             ? "Yes"
             : "No";
```

It can also be used in LINQ

```
var q = from a in things
        select a > 10
               ? "Greater than 10"
               : "Less than or equal to 10";
```

Or:

```
var q = from a in things
        let r = a > 10 
                ? "Greater than 10"
                : "Less than or equal to 10"
        select r;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691313(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: nice you are right +1 but i think this approach is not really helpful with decision trees. Right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was replying to the original question: "Is possible to convert traditional IF statements to functional ones?".  The standard if/else construct in C# is statement based, and therefore not functional.  For something to become functional it should be an expression; that is, both the 'then' and the 'else' branches should return a value of the same type that is then used as the result of the expression.  It's one of the few truly functional components of C#.  Other approaches might be to use monads to control flow.  I have a whole library on this: https://github.com/louthy/csharp-monad

Answer (score 2):

I once programmed a **decision tree** that consisted of decision nodes. It's too much code to share here, and I'm not even sure if I can do that, but I'll show what the API looks like:

```
private readonly DecisionNode<Client> _isReliableTree =
    DecisionNode.Create<Client>("Criminal record", client => client.CriminalRecord)
        .WhenTrue(false)
        .WhenFalse(DecisionNode.Create<Client>("Credit card", 
                                               client => client.UsesCreditCard)
           .WhenFalse(DecisionNode.Create<Client>("More than $40k", 
                                                  client => client.Income > 40000)
              .WhenFalse(DecisionNode.Create<Client>("More than 2 years in job", 
                                                     client => client.YearsInJob > 2))));
```

This builds a decision tree by which a `Client` object can be evaluated on its reliability (or credibility). The key is that a `WhenFalse` or `WhenTrue` method returns a new decision node that can be chained with new decisions or can evaluate to `true` or `false`. A node evaluates to `true` by default, which is why there are more `WhenFalse` nodes.

A typical use is

```
[TestMethod]
public void FullReliableClient_ShouldBeReliable()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(this._isReliableTree.Evaluate(ReliableClient));
}
```

where `ReliableClient` is a `Client` without a criminal record and meeting at least one of the tree other criteria.

I have to say that this was inspired by a talk of Scott Allen I heard once at some developers' event. And I've seen that there are many similar initiatives on the internet (look for "C# + decision tree").

Is it better that `if-then-else`? I don't think so. In the end I never used it in production code. Most business logic is too complicated to fit into a rigid decision tree that only evaluates one object. And IMO it doesn't make code better readable or maintainable.

A totally different approach to decisions without `if-then-else` is a [**state machine**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). When applied well, these can be very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I though a way to write functional `If` statements which look a lot more elegant than the simple `If`'s

### Simple If - Else:

```
void Main()
{
    (true && true).Then(() => Console.WriteLine("Printed out when condition == true"))
                  .Else(() => Console.WriteLine("Printed out when condition == false"));

    (true && false).Then(() => Console.WriteLine("Printed out when condition == true"))
                  .Else(() => Console.WriteLine("Printed out when condition == false"));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static class FunctionalExtensions
{
    private static bool OnConditionExecute(Action doSomething)
    {
        doSomething();
        return true;
    }

    //This is executed when condition == true
    public static bool Then(this bool condition, Action doSomething)
    {
        return (condition) && OnConditionExecute(doSomething);
    }

    //This is executed when condition == false
    public static bool Else(this bool condition, Action doSomething)
    {
        return (!condition) && OnConditionExecute(doSomething);
    }
}
```

### Multiple validation:

The following code addresses the problem i'm mentioning in the first place. It can be implemented with multiple nested nasty `If`'s but this approach is a lot better and proves the fact that traditional `If` statements are not suitable everywhere!

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(IsValid("hello"));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public bool IsValid(string name)
{
    Func<string, bool>[] rules = 
    {
        // Some whatever validation rules...
        n => string.IsNullOrEmpty(name),
        n => n.Length < 5 || n.Length > 50,
        n => n.Equals("hello")
    };
    return rules.All(r => r(name) == false);
}
```

Comment: It's definitely an intriguing idea. But it has a sort of forced feel, IMHO. Especially the method bodies for `Then()` and `Else()`, where imperatively expressed logic would work fine (and be hidden from callers). The biggest issue IMHO is that programs are chock full of conditionals, and this approach results in not only method calls (to the extension methods), but the proliferation of anonymous types in the assembly, and of instantiated objects and their delegates at run-time. This likely would make each conditional multiple orders of magnitude slower than the imperative alternative.

Comment: This is in no way reducing the level of nesting that you have; in fact, it's dramatically *increasing* the complexity of whatever nesting there might be (by introducing closure semantics and syntax) without any capacity to remove it.

Comment: @Servy is probable that with my approach things can equally get complex in some cases but allow me to disagree with you. In any case you are invited to write your own approach for clean IF statements.

Comment: @JorgeCode Don't you think that if there was a clean, simple alternative to `if` statements, it would be already used widely and integrated into modern programming languages?

Comment: @JorgeCode So you agree that your answer doesn't answer your own question, has significant problems, cannot provide any actual reasons for why it's better, but you're just stating that it's better?

Comment: @Servy i can understand your perspective and i can imaging some complicated structure with my implementation. However there is no actual problem that needs a solution but `IF` statements cannot be applied to every situation and one of them is decision trees! Personally i wanted to write down possible alternatives for different problems and give readability to my code. @Svick your argument is not valid. There are many languages and every language has its syntax and of course is not everything discovered. There are reasons and situations you can use something... Don't be so close minded.

Comment: In your "multiple validation" example, you don't need `if`s at all: `return !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || name.Length < 5 || name.Length > 50 || name == "hello");`. This code is simpler than your version and I think it's also more readable.

Comment: My friend @svick please don't look at my finger. Scale my example to something bigger...

Answer (score 0):

The following trick takes a number and prints a string. It can be modified to take a callback instead of a simple string.

```
//input: 1
//output: one

//input: 2
//output: two

//input: 3
//output: three

Func<string, bool> pr = s => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    return true;
};

string cr = Console.ReadLine();
int x = int.Parse(cr);

bool d = ((x == 1 && pr("one")) |
    (x==2 && pr("two")) |
    (x==3 && pr("three")));
```

Callback version:

```
Action<string> printSomething = s => Console.WriteLine(s);

Func<string, Action<string>, bool> pr = (s, a) => 
{
    a(s);
    return true;
};

string cr = Console.ReadLine();
int x = int.Parse(cr);

bool d = ((x == 1 && pr("one", printSomething)) |
    (x==2 && pr("two", printSomething)) |
    (x==3 && pr("three", printSomething)));
```